# Rails Proper Syntax for accessing errors of Model in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been struggling to figure this out for awhile now.

So in rails I have a home controller with action index which looks like this

```
  def index
   @contact = Contact.new if !defined? @contact #automatically create a contact variable 
  end
```

In index I am using the form_for (@contact) rails helper method - which automatically calls the create method of the contacts_controller. From the contacts_controller I redirect back to the index action of home controller. Here is what my create in contacts_controller looks like to clarify things.

```
  def create
   @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

   respond_to do |format|
       if @contact.save
          format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action =>"index", notice: 'Thanks for the Message!' } #
          format.json { render json: @contact, status: :created, location: @contact }
        else
          format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action =>"index", notice: 'Errors Occurred', errors: @contact.errors.full_messages, anchor: "#contact"}
          format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
   end
   end
```

**Here's my question!** How can I access @contact.errors from home/index ? Specifically I need to access errors individually @contact.errors[:name], @contact.errors[:email], etc. Thanks for the help in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually it's done with rendering templates where you handle error.

```
def create
   @contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])

   respond_to do |format|
       if @contact.save
          format.html { redirect_to :controller => 'home', :action =>"index", notice: 'Thanks for the Message!' } #
          format.json { render json: @contact, status: :created, location: @contact }
        else
          format.html { render :index } # Instead of redirecting, use render and in your template @contact.errors   
          format.json { render json: @contact.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
       end
   end
end
```

Also best practice to assing empty variable is

```
@contact ||= Contact.new
```